# How can I add keyboard functionality to my Tic Tac Toe game?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to add keyboard functionality in my tic tac toe game using JavaScript.
Currently I have it so that you can click wherever you want to to make the move. Everything works normally, but I'd like to make it so I can use the arrow keys to select the space to put the next move.
I.e. X moves to middle, use arrow key to move one space left, O places move, etc..
I feel like I was on the right track, but I really am not sure what else to do.

Here is the JS code:

```
const CIRCLE_CLASS = 'circle'
const WINNING_COMBINATIONS = [
  [0, 1, 2],
  [3, 4, 5],
  [6, 7, 8],
  [0, 3, 6],
  [1, 4, 7],
  [2, 5, 8],
  [0, 4, 8],
  [2, 4, 6]
]
const cellElements = document.querySelectorAll('[data-cell]')
const board = document.getElementById('board')
const winningMessageElement = document.getElementById('winningMessage')
const restartButton = document.getElementById('restartButton')
const winningMessageTextElement = document.querySelector('[data-winning-message-text]')
let circleTurn

startGame();

restartButton.addEventListener('click', startGame)

function startGame() {
  circleTurn = false
  cellElements.forEach(cell => {
    cell.classList.remove(X_CLASS)
    cell.classList.remove(CIRCLE_CLASS)
    cell.removeEventListener('click', handleClick)
    cell.addEventListener('click', handleClick, { once: true })
    cell.addEventListener("keydown", keyPushed)
  })
  setBoardHoverClass()
  winningMessageElement.classList.remove('show')
}

function keyPushed(e) {
  switch (e.keyCode) {
    case 37:
        handleClick(e);
        break;
    case 38:
        alert('up');
        break;
    case 39:
        alert('right');
        break;
    case 40:
        alert('down');
        break;
    case 79:
        alert('O');
        break;
    case 88:
        alert('X');
        break;
  }
}

function handleClick(e) {
  const cell = e.target
  const currentClass = circleTurn ? CIRCLE_CLASS : X_CLASS
  placeMark(cell, currentClass)
  if (checkWin(currentClass)) {
    endGame(false)
  } else if (isDraw()) {
    endGame(true)
  } else {
    swapTurns()
    setBoardHoverClass()
  }
}

function endGame(draw) {
  if (draw) {
    winningMessageTextElement.innerText = 'Draw!'
  } else {
    winningMessageTextElement.innerText = `${circleTurn ? "O's" : "X's"} Wins!`
  }
  winningMessageElement.classList.add('show')
}

function isDraw() {
  return [...cellElements].every(cell => {
    return cell.classList.contains(X_CLASS) || cell.classList.contains(CIRCLE_CLASS)
  })
}

function placeMark(cell, currentClass) {
  cell.classList.add(currentClass)
}

function swapTurns() {
  circleTurn = !circleTurn
}

function setBoardHoverClass() {
  board.classList.remove(X_CLASS)
  board.classList.remove(CIRCLE_CLASS)
  if (circleTurn) {
    board.classList.add(CIRCLE_CLASS)
  } else {
    board.classList.add(X_CLASS)
  }
}

function checkWin(currentClass) {
  return WINNING_COMBINATIONS.some(combination => {
    return combination.every(index => {
      return cellElements[index].classList.contains(currentClass)
    })
  })
}
```

Here is the CSS Code

```
*, *::after, *::before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  :root {
    --cell-size: 100px;
    --mark-size: calc(var(--cell-size) * .9);
  }
  
  body {
    margin: 0;
  }
  
  .board {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    display: grid;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    justify-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto)
  }
  
  .cell {
    width: var(--cell-size);
    height: var(--cell-size);
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  .cell:first-child,
  .cell:nth-child(2),
  .cell:nth-child(3) {
    border-top: none;
  }
  
  .cell:nth-child(3n + 1) {
    border-left: none;
  }
  
  .cell:nth-child(3n + 3) {
    border-right: none;
  }
  
  .cell:last-child,
  .cell:nth-child(8),
  .cell:nth-child(7) {
    border-bottom: none;
  }
  
  .cell.x,
  .cell.circle {
    cursor: not-allowed;
  }
  
  .cell.x::before,
  .cell.x::after,
  .cell.circle::before {
    background-color: black;
  }
  
  .board.x .cell:not(.x):not(.circle):hover::before,
  .board.x .cell:not(.x):not(.circle):hover::after,
  .board.circle .cell:not(.x):not(.circle):hover::before {
    background-color: lightgrey;
  }
  
  .cell.x::before,
  .cell.x::after,
  .board.x .cell:not(.x):not(.circle):hover::before,
  .board.x .cell:not(.x):not(.circle):hover::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: calc(var(--mark-size) * .15);
    height: var(--mark-size);
  }
  
  .cell.x::before,
  .board.x .cell:not(.x):not(.circle):hover::before {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
  
  .cell.x::after,
  .board.x .cell:not(.x):not(.circle):hover::after {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
  
  .cell.circle::before,
  .cell.circle::after,
  .board.circle .cell:not(.x):not(.circle):hover::before,
  .board.circle .cell:not(.x):not(.circle):hover::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
  }
  
  .cell.circle::before,
  .board.circle .cell:not(.x):not(.circle):hover::before {
    width: var(--mark-size);
    height: var(--mark-size);
  }
  
  .cell.circle::after,
  .board.circle .cell:not(.x):not(.circle):hover::after {
    width: calc(var(--mark-size) * .7);
    height: calc(var(--mark-size) * .7);
    background-color: white;
  }
  
  .winning-message {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .9);
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    color: white;
    font-size: 5rem;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  
  .winning-message button {
    font-size: 3rem;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: .25em .5em;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  .winning-message button:hover {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    border-color: white;
  }
  
  .winning-message.show {
    display: flex;
  }
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  /* Background Styles Only */
  
  @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway');
  
  * {
      font-family: Raleway;
  }
  
  .side-links {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: 15px;
  }
  
  .side-link {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    color: white;
    width: 180px;
    padding: 10px 0;
    border-radius: 10px;
  }
```

Here is the HTML code:

```
<html lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'/>
    <title>Twitter Tic Tac Toe</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='styles.css'>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="board" id="board">
        <div class="cell" data-cell></div>
        <div class="cell" data-cell></div>
        <div class="cell" data-cell></div>
        <div class="cell" data-cell></div>
        <div class="cell" data-cell></div>
        <div class="cell" data-cell></div>
        <div class="cell" data-cell></div>
        <div class="cell" data-cell></div>
        <div class="cell" data-cell></div>
      </div>
      <div class="winning-message" id="winningMessage">
        <div data-winning-message-text></div>
        <button id="restartButton">Restart</button>
      </div>   
    <script src='index.js'></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `document.onkeydown =  e=>{ switch(e.key){ case 'ArrowUp': /* do stuff */ break; case 'ArrowRight': /* do stuff */ break; case 'ArrowDown': /* do stuff */ break; case 'ArrowLeft': /* do stuff */ break; } }`

Comment: What the above comment is saying : just add the keydown listeners to the document and not to the individual cells. Then you can keep track of on what cell the "cursor" is in a variable.